# How can I print content outside my @page margin?

Tags: html, css

In my css, i have @page margins all around. I am trying to print something on top of my margin (like a footer) that spans all pages. So I am trying to find a code to ignore my @page margins.

I am using itext to print out the pdf on the page.

If i set margin: -5px, it just gets hidden behind the margin (I can see part of the top showing, and the bottom half is missing)

```
@page {
    margin-top: 1cm;
    margin-left: 1cm;
    margin-right: 1cm;
    margin-bottom: 3cm;
    size: A4 landscape; 
}

div.footerPosition {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
}
```

I expect to print over the margin, instead of being hidden by the margin

Comment: Couldn't seem to find a solution, but my workaround which is absolutely not ideal but works if anyone needs it, was to just create an image and use it as a background image for the page.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code

```css
@page :left {
margin: 0.5cm;
}

@page :right {
margin: 0.8cm;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the question at all. They aren't asking how to have different margins on left and right larges.